# Bootstrap 4 not responsive on mobile, columns stack over each other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

My website looks fine on desktop, however I'm having difficulty making sure the website is responsive on mobile using bootstrap 4.

I'm using custom columns that I have used before and they always seemed to work however with this project the **columns are on top of each other** rather than stacking after each other.

I believe it may be because this project is very specific.  Or perhaps it's because I have background photos for each `<sections>` of my html page. I have many sections so I will only provide a few sections of my HTML code. If anyone can let me know if I'm writing my columns incorrectly I would greatly appreciate it!

**Example:**

[image]

The section 4 content is over section 3 content on mobile devices.

**HTML:**

```
 <!--Section 3-->
    <div id="content3">
        <section>
            <h1 class="text-center integration">Integrating</h1>
            <div class="container-fluid integration_background">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <ul class="integrations">
                            <li><img src="img/g_suite.png" class="pr-4">
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="img/_slack.png" class="pl-4 pr-4">
                            </li>
                            <li><img src="img/groupme.png" class="pl-4 pr-4">
                            </li>
                            <li> <img src="img/microsoft.png" class="pl-4">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!--Section 4 -->
    <div id="content4">
        <section>
            <h1 class="text-center">Pricing</h1>
            <br>
            <div class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center" style="width: 75%;" id="price_container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Educator</div>
                            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                                <img src="img/price_edu.png" class="img-fluid">
                                <h6 class="card-title">Use Wanzeru Ed</h6>
                                <hr>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Free for one class</li>
                                    <li>Matches students in ideal teams</li>
                                    <li>Real-time feedback</li>
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block mt-auto" style="background-color: #2F8EE1; bottom:5px;">Get Quotes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4  text-center">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Individual</div>
                            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                                <img src="img/price_entur.png" class="img-fluid">
                                <h6 class="card-title">Hire Wanzeru to be your meeting (Find word)</h6>
                                <hr>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>$9.99/month</li>
                                    <li>Schedules unlimited meetings</li>
                                    <li>Facilitates unlimited meetings</li>
                                    <li>Takes meeting notes</li>
                                    <li>Assigns meeting tasks</li>
                                    <li>Sends reminders</li>
                                    <li>Digital badging for skills</li>
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block mt-auto" style="background-color: #2F8EE1;">$9.99/ month</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4  text-center">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Entrepreneur</div>
                            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                                <img src="img/price_indi.png" class="img-fluid">
                                <h6 class="card-title">Hire Wanzeru for your business team</h6>
                                <hr>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Schedules all team meetings</li>
                                    <li>Facilitates every meetings</li>
                                    <li>Takes meeting notes</li>
                                    <li>Assigns meeting tasks</li>
                                    <li>Sends reminders</li>
                                    <li>Digital badging for skills</li>
                                    <li>Provides real time progress reports of each team</li>
                                    <li>Fully compliant with each business data policy</li>
                                </ul>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block mt-auto" style="background-color: #2F8EE1;">Get Quotes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content3 {
    background-image: url("img/back2.png");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 540px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.integration {
    margin-top: -180px;
    color: #fff;
}

.integration_background {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.vertical_line {
    width: 1px;
    height: 110%;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
}

#content4 {
    margin-top: -120px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with the code you posted:  
  
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/oPLNra
  
You mentioned that this is only a sample of your HTML though. What you might want to do is try commenting out sections of your complete page to see if you can isolate the cause, or alternatively, post a URL to the full page.  
  
Good luck!

Comment: I figured out what it was. In my CSS I have different heights for each section as well as margins, this is why they are overlapping each other. Once I take the heights and margins off in the developer tools, its all responsive perfectly. It appears the only way to keep my desktop as is and make mobile responsive to to do media queries, which is a bummer. It's only like this because the background images are not perfectly square, they have their own unique shape and are transparent. To make everything fit perfectly I had to change the heights and margins.

Answer (score -1):

After further review there was nothing wrong with my bootstrap columns, which made me very happy. :) This is what is was - my background images are all different sizes and are not perfectly square, they are also transparent. So, when I'm adding text and trying to make sure it's centered on top of those background images, I had to change the margin-top and bottoms on pretty much all my sections. This caused the responsive side to be all jacked up.

The solution is I have to do a ton of media queries for phone and tablet sizes. Not fun, but it has to get done. I really hope this helps someone out in the future because it was mind boggling to me.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a `<br>` tag. I don't know if your CSS is inline but you'll need `<style>` and `</style>` tags. Maybe this is why alignment is off?

Comment: Yup,  I have <br> after every section. And my CSS file is separate from my HTML file, I'm importing it.